# How do I add multiple text color ( stroke: ) and ( fill: )

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="apc" style="overflow: hidden">
  <div class="ee" style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Scheherazade New', serif;"> <canvas id="input-canvas" :width="canvasStyle.width" :height="canvasStyle.height" v-show="false"> </canvas> <canvas id="watermark"> </canvas> <img :src="imgSrc" />
```

```
form: {
        message: 'my text',
        img: new Image,
        local_img: null,
        font_family: 'Scheherazade New',
        font_size: '55',
        color: 'rgba(2, 9, 1, 9.3',
        position_x: '90',
        position_y: '280',
        rotate_deg: '-30',
        real_size: true,
        freeze_ratio: true,
        tile_flag: false,
        real_tile_flag: false,
        watermark_width: '300',
        watermark_height: '100',
        
        
    },
```

[image]

Comment: dear the image is not there

Comment: <div id="apc" style="overflow: hidden">
       <div class="ee" style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Scheherazade New', serif;">
        <canvas id="input-canvas" :width="canvasStyle.width" :height="canvasStyle.height"  v-show="false" >
        </canvas>
  
        <canvas id="watermark">
  
  </canvas>
  
        <img :src="imgSrc"/>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)